# StandardInput=socket service fails to run

Tags: systemd

I have a simple socket/service pair where the service relies on stdin from the socket:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/simple.socket
[Unit]
Description=Simple socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=11111
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/simple.service
[Unit]
Description=Simple service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-cat -
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
```

When I try to launch with `netcat 127.0.0.1 11111` I get:

```
- simple.service - "Simple service"
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/simple.service; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2020-05-19 09:42:17 CEST; 11min ago
TriggeredBy: simple.socket
    Process: 400879 ExecStart=/bin/cat - (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 400879 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

- simple.socket - "Simple socket"
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/simple.socket; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Tue 2020-05-19 09:42:17 CEST; 11min ago
   Triggers: simple.service
     Listen: [::]:11111 (Stream)
```

My guess is that `cat` is failing to start because it is trying to connect to `stdin` which is not available.  If I replace `cat -` with `sleep infinity` the service starts fine.  I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has to do with the `Accept=` option of a socket.

This version will work:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/simple.socket
[Unit]
Description=Simple socket

[Socket]
Accept=yes
ListenStream=11111
```

Note the new filepath

```
# /etc/systemd/system/simple@.service
[Unit]
Description=Simple service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-cat -
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
```

Now `nc 127.0.0.1 11111` does not return and lets you echo back whatever you send.  Also `systemctl status simple*` now gives:

```
- simple.socket - Simple socket
     Loaded: loaded /etc/systemd/system/simple.socket; static: vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (listening) since Tue 2020-05-19 10:04:48 CEST; 48s ago
   Triggers: simple@1-127.0.0.1:11111-127.0.0.1:47194.service
     Listen: [::]:11111 (Stream)
   Accepted: 2; Connected: 1;
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 9429)
     Memory: 120.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/simple.socket

- simple@1-127.0.0.1:11111-127.0.0.1:47194.service - "Simple service" (127.0.0.1:47194)
     Loaded: loaded /etc/systemd/system/simple@.service; static: vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-05-19 10:04:48 CEST; 48s ago
TriggeredBy: simple.socket
   Main PID: 403830 (cat)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9429)
     Memory: 184.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-simple.slice/simple@1-127.0.0.1:11111-127.0.0.1:47194.service
             -403830 /bin/cat -
```

I assume this works because when `Accept=no`, each connection tries to connect to the same process, and it's a bit strange trying to mux several sockets into a single stdin. With `Accept=yes` each connection spawns a new process and so it's simple to simply pipe the socket into the stdin of each process.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong.  The correct answer is that `cat` does not call `accept()` and so isn't compatible with being passed a _listening_ socket as its standard input.